# Fibonacci Heaps without array indexing?

Tags: heap, computer-science, amortized-analysis

Friends, my professor covered Fibonacci heaps and gave a home work. The requirement is usually after a extract, we need to compress the root list by linking roots of same degree. We use array indexing to find another element of same degree. But now imagine that you don't have array indexing capabilities in your system. Implement extract using some data structures and additional pointers so that you can achieve same amortized time!!

I've broken my head over this but I'm not getting any ideas. Any clues or inputs???

Comment: I'm confused about a programming environment that wouldn't let you index into an array.

Comment: Its not about a programming environment... he just has given an imaginary restriction that array indexing should not be used.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes more sense. :)

Comment: Define "without indexing". You say an imaginary restriction, which sounds very imaginary because I don't any other way to get at an array without an index. Maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Comment: I think he just wants you to use an actual tree, rather than an array as is typically done.

Comment: While you say no index? What, Can you use linkad list as A=[value, nextA]?